# JDBC no suitable driver found just on Linux?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am coding a server at the moment I am developing it on a windows system with intellij idea and I want to run it on a Linux server(Debian).
On my windows PC all runs great I can connect my program to the SQL-server on my windows but when I "compile" the program and let it run on a Linux server I always get a `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql/localhost:3306/...` exception and a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` exception.

My code

```
public class DataBaseHandler {




//Dieses Objekt stellt die Verbindung zur Datenbank da
private Connection connection;
private String dbName = "legitName";
private String hostName = "localhost:3306";
private String loginName = "legitName";
private String pw = "legitPW";




private Controller c;
public DataBaseHandler(Controller c){
    this.c = c;
    connectToDb();

}

//Methode um eine Verbindung mit der Datenbank herzustellen
private void connectToDb(){

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("rude german words here");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String connectCommand = "jdbc:mysql://"+hostName+"/"+dbName+""+"?useSSL=false&user="+loginName+"&password="+pw;
    try {

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectCommand);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //tstQuery();

}
```

so as already mentioned this runs perfect on my windows and I can even execute the "testQuery()" method which gives me back some resluts but on my server the line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` causes the "ClassNotFoundException" and the `DriverManager.getConnection()` line causes the SQLexception.
In Intellij under project structure I added the

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar
```

to the Classpath under SDK
and also to the Global Libaries.

The Linux server is also running MySql DB.

Comment: When you run it on the Linux server, the mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar must be in the classpath .

Comment: put the jar into the java classpath when your run `java -cp .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar YourMainClass`

Comment: Please read the last sentences :) I've added it to the classpath of my project. But if I've done it wrong, what surely is possible, it'd be nice if you correct me because than I have no idea how to do it :D

Comment: Are you generating a `.war` file from your project or a `.jar` ?

Comment: @SergeyBenner thanks first for you comment.
I am a real Linux noob so could you explain this maybe more pricisly?
So if my server programm is named **server.jar** and my main is called **Controller.class** would it be like
`java -cp server.jar .:mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar Controller.class `?

Comment: @ammoQ I am creating a .jar archive

Comment: It would rather be `java -cp server.jar:/mein/persoenlicher/pfad/zu/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar Controller`

Comment: `java -cp .:server.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar full.package.name.if.any.Controller`

Comment: If you think you added that JAR to the CLASSPATH, and you still get CNF exception, it means you did it incorrectly.  Believe the JVM.

Comment: @duffymo sooooo I need to add the complete.zip instead of .jar fomr the connector? :'D

Comment: No.  Wrong.  You need to add the MySQL connector JAR correctly at runtime.

Comment: @SergeyBenner that sadly didn't help :/

Comment: @duffymo sorry could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: You either understand Java CLASSPATH or you don't.  Please do some research.  You can't write Java without knowing how CLASSPATH works.

Comment: Where on your linux box is `mysql-connector-java-‌​5.1.41-bin.jar` located?

Comment: Make sure your connection URL format is correct: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Thanks to all it works now :) wrote the wrong path for mysql-connector!

Comment: @alovaros put all the jars into one folder for simplicity and use there the commandline i wrote above. you may also try and use  `--classpath` instead of `-cp` just pretty much the same.

Comment: I'll do thank you :)